# SQL command for PROGRESS database

Tags: sql, join, progress-db

Please bear with me new to SQL- I am trying to write an SQL command with a join in a PROGRESS db. I would like to then select only the first matching record from the join. I thought to use LIMIT but PROGRESS does not support that. MIN or TOP would also work I think but having trouble with the syntax. Here is current syntax:

```
SELECT esthead_0."k-est-code", estdie_0."estd-size2", estdie_0."k-cmp-no", estdie_0."estd-cal"
  FROM VISION.PUB.estdie estdie_0 
INNER JOIN VISION.PUB.esthead esthead_0 ON estdie_0."k-est-code" = esthead_0."k-est-code"
 WHERE estdie_0."k-cmp-no" = (SELECT MIN("k-cmp-no") 
                                FROM VISION.PUB.estdie estdie_0 )
```

This will select the MIN from the whole table but I would like the MIN of the records the join returns for each "k-est-code".

Comment: What's a PROGRESS database? postgres maybe?

Comment: PROGRESS is right, its a company that sells its own version of a rdbms just like ORACLE and MS.  Although not as popular...we were being sold on a PROGRESS system thank goodness we said no to that...

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're accomplishing, you need to use Aggregate functions and GROUP BY.

Here is the correct query:

```
SELECT esthead_0."k-est-code", estdie_0."estd-size2", MIN(estdie_0."k-cmp-no") AS k-cmp-no-minimum, estdie_0."estd-cal"
  FROM VISION.PUB.estdie estdie_0 
  INNER JOIN VISION.PUB.esthead esthead_0 ON estdie_0."k-est-code" = esthead_0."k-est-code"
 GROUP BY esthead_0."k-est-code", estdie_0."estd-size2", estdie_0."estd-cal"
```

The general syntax for adding a GROUP BY / Aggregate query is:

1. use an aggregate function like MIN(), MAX(), AVG(), SUM() to select which column you want ... (choose the function depending on whether you want minimum, maximum etc).  There are those I listed which are standard, and then often your database will give you some additional ones as well.
2. Add every other column you're selecting EXCEPT the ones in the function to a GROUP BY at the end of your query.
3. Your GROUP BY has to occur after your WHERE, but before your ORDER BY.
4. If you want to do WHERE-like filtering on the function (say you wanted only k-cmp-no over 100), you use HAVING after the group by, e.g.:

   HAVING MIN(estdie_0."k-cmp-no") > 100

Google for Group By and Aggregate functions for more info on this SQL concept.  It works the same in all databases as it's standard ANSI SQL.  See this page for a more thorough introduction with examples: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

Progress (OE 11.2) supports OFFSET FETCH which is same as LIMIT OFFSET in mysql.

Example:

```
SQLExplorer>select FirstName , LastName , EmpNum from pub.employee order by empnum offset 10 rows fetch next 10 rows only;
FirstName                      LastName                                                EmpNum
------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------- -----------
Frank                          Garsen                                                      11
Jenny                          Morris                                                      12
Luke                           Sanders                                                     13
Marcy                          Adams                                                       14
Alex                           Simons                                                      15
Holly                          Atkins                                                      16
Larry                          Barry                                                       17
Jean                           Brady                                                       18
Larry                          Dawsen                                                      19
Dan                            Flanagan                                                    20
```

Hope this helps